# How to create list of objects in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to kotlin, how could i create a list of object then to be user in a ListView in Android?

I have created a Class called Articolo.kt that looks like this:

```
data class Articolo(var barcode: String, var qty: Number)
```

So the data passed to it should be "barcode" and "qty" then the "barcode" will be a unique key and if an item with it exist i will need to increment "qty" instead of adding a new to the list.

Then here is my function where i make my controlls and adding the data to the class:

```
private fun addBarcode() {
    val barcode = txtBarcode.text.toString()
    val qta = txtQta.text.toString().toInt()
    if (barcode.trim() == "") {
        txtBarcode.requestFocus()
        return;
    }

    Articolo(barcode, qta)

}
```

So at this point i have my object Articolo with my data, but how can i add it to a list / collection which i could access from my another fragment and use it in a ListView?

Answer (score 4):

To create a list of data in kotlin you need to simple do it this way

```
  var list = arrayOf(" here you pass the type of data you want")

  **Int Example
  var list = arrayOf(1,2,3)

  ** String example
  var list = arrayOf("string1","string2,"string3");
```

- If you want to use model class , you can use mutablelist

```
 **you init a list 
 private var mylist : MutableList<Articolo>? = null

 ** then in your oncreate you reference it 
  mylist = mutableListOf()

 ** you can add your object class this way
 var Articolo = Articolo("barcode","qty")
 mylist.add(Articolo)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private var mylist =  mutableListOf<Articolo>()


//find the same barcode and add the qty,otherwise add Articolo(barcode, qta) to list
mylist.find{
   it.barcode==barcode
}?.let{
   it.qty+=qta
}?:{
   mylist.add(Articolo(barcode, qta))
}
```

find the same barcode and add the qty,otherwise add Articolo(barcode, qta) to list

Ps:as the question in [unable-to-change-an-object-property-in-mutablelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65772605/unable-to-change-an-object-property-in-mutablelist/65772705?noredirect=1#comment116295015_65772705),you should not use Number as a type