# Unable to change an object property in MutableList

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to change quantity in my MutableList of an Object if there is yet that object with same ID in the list, the issue is that i'm getting bunch of errors when trying to do `it.qty += qty`

Here is a screen of what android studio is saying:

[image]

If it would be useful here is my Articolo class code:

```
data class Articolo(var barcode: String, var qta: Number) {
    constructor() : this ("", 0)
}
```

And the code from the screenshot:

```
private var articoli = mutableListOf<Articolo>()
    articoli.find{
        it.barcode==barcode
    }?.let{
        it.qta += qta
    }?:{
        articoli.add(Articolo(barcode, qta))
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't defined qta as Number,Number is an interface ,it has no  plus method

defined it as Int  Long  Double or other special type

Comment: both are Number type

Comment: can't Number,Number is interface  no  plus method

Comment: while why the ELSE part of the code is set as unused?

Comment: it's not show unused in my android studio。the else part work when the find return null,it means not found the same code in the list,so there do the add method.

Comment: you can remove the {},just  articoli.add(Articolo(barcode, qta))